# fade out other divs on hover div

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to figure out how to fade all divs but the one that is being hovered. here is my code so far, I can only get it to fade the one being hovered not all the onse not being hovered.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.fadeHover').hover(

    function () {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.3);
    },

    function () {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);
    });
});

<div class="fadeHover fadeDiv">
    <p>1</p>
</div>
<div class="fadeDiv fadeHover">
    <p>2</p>
</div>
<div class="fadeDiv fadeHover">
    <p>3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/RjH4a/2/)

You can do it simply by making use of jquery `not()` selector and `this` follows

```
$('.fadeHover').hover(
   function () {
    $('.fadeHover').not(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.3);
   },
    function () {
    $('.fadeHover').fadeTo('slow', 1);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fadeDiv').hover(function(){
        $('.fadeDiv').fadeTo('slow', 0.3);
        $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
$('.fadeHover').hover(

    function(){
        var current = $(this);
        $('.fadeHover').each(function(){
            if ($(this) !== current) $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.3);
        });
    },

    function(){
        var current = $(this);
        $('.fadeHover').each(function(){
            if ($(this) !== current) $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);
        });
    }

);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/RjH4a/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.fadeHover').hover(

    function () {
        $('.fadeHover').stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.3);
        $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);
    },
    function () {
        $('.fadeHover').stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);
    });
});
```

Slash's solution works too, it's more efficient but is more code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document.body)
        .on('mouseenter', '.fadeHover', function () {
            $('.fadeHover:not(:hover)').stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.3);
        })
        .on('mouseleave', '.fadeHover', function () {
            $('.fadeHover:not(:hover)').stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);
        });
});
```

---

And this can be done with pure CSS3:

```
.fade-container .fade-hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .5s linear;
}

.fade-container:hover .fade-hover {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.fade-container:hover .fade-hover:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

With HTML:

```
<div class="fade-container">
    <div class="fade-hover">
        <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fade-hover">
        <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fade-hover">
        <p>3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```